# How to transpose/cast two variables to one line?

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I need to turn this

```
id  |  amount |  day
---------------------
 A  |   10    |  0 
 A  |   54    |  8
 A  |   23    |  18
 A  |   43    |  28
 A  |   87    |  51
 B  |   34    |  0
 B  |   76    |  1 
 B  |   12    |  7
```

into this

```
id | a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 | a5 | d1 | d2 | d3 | d4 | d5 
--------------------------------------------------------
 A | 10 | 54 | 23 | 43 | 87 | 0  |  8 | 18 | 28 | 51
 B | 34 | 76 | 12 | 0  |  0 | 0  |  1 |  7 | 0  | 0
```

ie. transpose/cast the rows of the df to an unknown number of columns by id, putting zeros where there would be empty values because of the inequal length.

I've experimented with

```
df <- data.frame(id=c('A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B'),    amount=c(10,54,23,43,87,34,76,12), day=c(0,8,18,28,51,0,1,7))
library(reshape2)
x <- dcast(df, id ~ day, mean, value = 'amount')
```

but it's not quite right. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use base R `reshape()` after introducing a "time" variable:

```
df$time <- ave(as.numeric(as.character(df$id)), df$id, FUN = seq_along)
df
#   id amount day time
# 1  A     10   0    1
# 2  A     54   8    2
# 3  A     23  18    3
# 4  A     43  28    4
# 5  A     87  51    5
# 6  B     34   0    1
# 7  B     76   1    2
# 8  B     12   7    3
reshape(df, direction = "wide", idvar="id", timevar="time")
#   id amount.1 day.1 amount.2 day.2 amount.3 day.3 amount.4 day.4 amount.5 day.5
# 1  A       10     0       54     8       23    18       43    28       87    51
# 6  B       34     0       76     1       12     7       NA    NA       NA    NA
```

Optional steps:

1. Reorganize column order:

   ```
   df2 <- df2[c("id", 
                grep("amount", names(df2), value=TRUE), 
                grep("day", names(df2), value = TRUE))]
   ```
2. Replace `NA` with `0`:

   ```
   df2[is.na(df2)] <- 0
   df2
   #   id amount.1 amount.2 amount.3 amount.4 amount.5 day.1 day.2 day.3 day.4 day.5
   # 1  A       10       54       23       43       87     0     8    18    28    51
   # 6  B       34       76       12        0        0     0     1     7     0     0
   ```

Comment: @agstudy, thanks. I think that the `as.numeric` part is actually not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I have to create a new variable dd

```
df$dd <-unlist(by(df$id,df$id, FUN= function(x)seq(1,length(x))))


id amount day dd
1  A     10   0  1
2  A     54   8  2
3  A     23  18  3
4  A     43  28  4
5  A     87  51  5
6  B     34   0  1
7  B     76   1  2
8  B     12   7  3

mm <- melt(df,id.vars=c('id','dd'),measure.vars=c('amount','day'))
dcast(mm,id~variable+dd,fun.aggregate=mean)
id amount_1 amount_2 amount_3 amount_4 amount_5 day_1 day_2 day_3 day_4 day_5
1  A       10       54       23       43       87     0     8    18    28    51
2  B       34       76       12      NaN      NaN     0     1     7   NaN   NaN
```

**EDIT**
To get a nice ouput with 0 , I replace mean with a custom function

```
dcast(mm,id~variable+dd,fun.aggregate=
                       function(x) ifelse(is.nan(mean(x)),0,mean(x)))
  id amount_1 amount_2 amount_3 amount_4 amount_5 day_1 day_2 day_3 day_4 day_5
1  A       10       54       23       43       87     0     8    18    28    51
2  B       34       76       12        0        0     0     1     7     0     0
```